How do i handle interpolated Animated and dot indicator gracefully while I have a copy of data list?
I want to create a bidirectional swiper my own, but I have a problem about to seek a way how do i handle the interpolated. here's my swiper so far
Swiper.js
import React, {useCallback, useRef} from 'react';
import {Animated, View} from 'react-native';

const Swiper = ({
  RenderItem = () => null,
  data = [],
  RenderDotIndicator = false,
  containerWidth = 0,
}) => {
  const refAnimated = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  // here I copy the data that I got from props
  // so if the data is [1,2] it would be [1,2,1,2]
  const [InternalData, setInternalData] = React.useState([...data, ...data]);

  // here I want to handle that interpolated only used 2 length instead of 4
  const interpolateFunct = (outputRange, index) =>
    refAnimated.interpolate({
      inputRange: [
        (index - 1) * width,
        index * width,
        (index + 1) * width,
      ],
      outputRange,
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });

  const WrappedRenderItem = useCallback(
    ({item, index}) => (
      <View style={{overflow: 'hidden', width: width}}>
        {RenderItem({item, index})}
      </View>
    ),
    [],
  );

  const WrappedRenderDotIndicator = useCallback(() => {
    const dotItem = data.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <Animated.View
          key={'dot' + item + index.toString()}
          style={{
            width: 6,
            backgroundColor: '#D3D3D3',
            height: 6,
            borderRadius: 6 / 2,
            marginHorizontal: 5,
            transform: [{scale: interpolateFunct([1, 2, 1], index)}],
          }}
        />
      );
    });
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignSelf: 'center',
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 6,
        }}
      >
        {dotItem}
      </View>
    );
  }, [RenderDotIndicator]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Animated.FlatList
        ref={refAnimated}
        data={InternalData}
        renderItem={WrappedRenderItem}
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {x: refAnimated}}}],
          {useNativeDriver: true},
        )}
      />
      <WrappedRenderDotIndicator />
    </View>
  );
};

Swiper.displayName = 'Swiper';

export default Swiper;


currently, using the code above, I got this behaviour (notice the dot indicator when I sliding from 2nd to 3rd image, the dot is not reflecting the first one)
https://jmp.sh/JeFQ2CbF (or run snippet below)


<div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0;"><iframe src="https://jumpshare.com/embed/IFu1Zeev0hccyrbvqm9h" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe></div>



How do I handle when sliding from 2nd to 3rd, the dot indicator reflecting the first one?

anyone has an insight?
